# Why is my stored procedure not filling in rows and updated rows = -1

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, merge, db2

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will update two columns in a table based on information from another table. However, when I try to execute the procedure, the columns are not filled and I'm told that updated rows = -1.

This is the code that I'm using.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE Merge_Tables 
    (@tableName nvarchar(50), 
    @colName nvarchar(50), 
    @schemaName nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO @tableName
    USING TABLE1.CODETABLE AS SRC ON SRC.ORIGINAL_VALUE = @tableName.@colName
                                  AND SRC."SCHEMA" = '@schemaName'
                                  AND SRC."TABLE" = '@tableName'

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE 
        SET GROUP_6 = SRC.GROUP_6
            GROUP_18 = SRC.GROUP_18;
END
```

```sql
EXECUTE MERGE_TABLES @tablename = 'TEST_TABLE', @colName = 'DERIVED_CODES', @schemaName = 'TEST_SCHEMA'
```

Comment: You need to use dynamic-SQL when the SQL statement final text is not unknown until runtime, i.e  PREPARE and EXECUTE .  Look it up.